# Loading content from another webpage into Magento Product Specifications

Tags: html, magento, attributes

**To clarify the goal:**

Currently I have a CSV File.

File contains "Specifications" attribute. There is a Web URL directing to the Specifications Content for the select product.

I want to know how to load this content without having to copy and paste the whole page. Can I do this just by having the URL?

**End-Goal:**

To have the Specifications Content displayed in Specifications attribute on my Magento Product page, through use of the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can create attribute named `specification`. Set `Catalog Input Type for Store Owner` to `Text Area` and `Enable WYSIWYG` to `Yes`. Also set `Visible on Product View Page on Front-end` to `Yes`. Then you can store such specification data with html in this attribute and it will be displayed in front end (page).

Comment: Hi, sorry I don't think I was too clear on the situation. I currently have a CSV file with Specifications Webpage Links (www.abc.com/abc123.html for example)- Different link for each product. I would like to auto-Load that webpage's content directly using the webpage url, is this do-able?

Comment: Any idea if it's possible to load content through an URL? Please help, thanks!